# Enable and restarting crontab in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a laravel cron that I would like to run/ restart each time container is deployed or restarted, but I cant make the service run in Ansible 2.9 . Running it manually inside the conatiner works fine.

```
   - name: run the scheduled commands a specific file
     shell: docker exec -it project_1 service cron restart
```

But ansible is complaining with the error

```
    cron start", "delta": "0:00:00.086710", "end": "2020-11-20 
    14:32:47.259508", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": 
    "2020-11-20 14:32:47.172798", "stderr": "Got permission denied 
    while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
    unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get 
    http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/project_1/json: 
    dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied", 
    "stderr_lines": ["Got permission denied while trying to connect to 
    the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:  
   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"], 
   "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

And my crontab looks like this

```
   * * * * * root  . /root/.profile; /usr/local/bin/php /opt/app/public/../artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I know its a permission issue, I donthave the idea how because the `/var/run/docker.sock` only created once the cron command is being called. I also tried to set the permission in Dockerfile by adding

```
 RUN sudo chmod 666 /var/run/socket.sock
```

But it gives me error as the file doesnt exist yet

Its working actually if I run manually inside the container

```
   service cron restart
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You did not paste the full error message. If it does not contain much more (e.g. a reason for the fail), you should run ansible-playbook in verbose mode (`-vvv`) to see if you can get more info.

Comment: @Zeitounator I updated my question, hope its more clearer.

Comment: The user you use to connect to your target system from ansible does not have the right to execute docker commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question, since I found the solution that worked.

```
  - name: run the scheduled commands during reboot or deploy
    become: yes
    shell: docker exec -it --user root project_1 service cron start
```

So I just added the user that owns the cron, in this case its `root`